# Всплывающая подсказка css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Наводим на текст-всплывает подсказка.
Как наилучшим образом реализовать подобное?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если проект на бутстрапе, используйте встроенные компоненты. `tooltip` (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) или `popover` (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ну в общем вот так это делается !**

> *смотреть на весь экран*

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function l_tooltip(target_items, name) {
    $(target_items).each(function(i) {        
      $("body").append("<div class='" + name + "' id='" + name + i + "'><p>" + $(this).attr('title') + "</p></div>");        
      var tooltip = $("#" + name + i);        
      if ($(this).attr("title") != "" && $(this).attr("title") != "undefined") {        
        $(this).removeAttr("title").mouseover(function() {                
          tooltip.css({
            opacity: 0.9,
            display: "none"
          }).fadeIn(30);        
        }).mousemove(function(kmouse) {                
          tooltip.css({
            left: kmouse.pageX + 15,
            top: kmouse.pageY + 15
          });        
        }).mouseout(function() {                
          tooltip.fadeOut(10);        
        });        
      }    
    });
  }
  l_tooltip(".ttp_lnk a", "tooltip");
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  z-index: 999;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #323232;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}

.tooltip p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.ttp_lnk {
  max-width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ttp_lnk h1 {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px!important;
  max-height: 150px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.ppt_p {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ttp_lnk">
  <a href="#" title="<h1>Это пример универсальной всплывающей подсказки на jQuery</h1> Это нормальный текст<b>Это жирный текст</b><br /><i>Это наклонный текст</i><s>Это зачёркнутый текст</s><b style='color: red;'>Это жирный текст красного цвета</b>Ещё<sub>совсем</sub>немного<sup>текста</sup><img src='http://www.memphiswebprogramming.com/sites/default/files/pictures/jquery-modern-logo.jpg' />Вобщем видно что можно использовать форматирование текста в данном тултипе, так же как и картнинки, но пока есть загвоздка с картинками-ссылками.<br /> Применение данного тултипа ОЧЕНЬ широко, стоит только включить воображение.">Наведите на эту ссылку курсор</a>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```